# DataGrid scrollbar issue when column resizing

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resize, flicker

When resizing a column, there seems to be a strange flicker issue when the column reaches the flirting point with text wrapping. Since this is hard to explain, I've recorded the issue with a sample grid and uploaded a video of it here: http://tinypic.com/r/15zfdiu/6

Notice that shrinking the column has a strange effect before the column content actually needs to be wrapped, and same when expanding it. Just to be clear, the numbers being wrapped is completely normal, it's the flicker that happens before it is wrapped that is the issue. Has anyone ever run into this before?

Edit: This doesn't only occur with this particular datagrid, but others as well (so it's not a data issue).

Comment: Can you show us the XAML?...looks like a layout glitch. I notice your font shrinks down in size...you using a ViewBox? in that Header?

Comment: Ouf, we use very heavily customized datagrids and most of it is templated... would it be possible for some potential areas where this layout glitch can be found (e.g. XAML for the ScrollBar, etc)?

And yes, we do use a Viewbox in the column headers

Comment: Could you try without a ViewBox...it could be that when scaling dont the font...it briefly switches to a font substitution...which is..a wacky size....just an idea. Try a different Font too.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the Viewbox and changed the font, and no luck with either. The problem seems to be with the columns themselves, they seem to juggle between needing to wrap its contents based on the scrollbar visibility (since the scrollbar is wide, when it is visible the column will need to text wrap, but if it's not visible then textwrapping is not necessary)

Comment: You could set it show the scrollbar visibility to show always...it will just be disabled when there is nothing to scroll....then it won't affect your layout. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility